# Control the output of subcalls to `make`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile where one of the goals looks as follows:

```
task: $(foreach t,$(SUBDIRS),subtask_$t)

subtask_%:
        make -C $* subtask
```

In words, `task` runs the `subtask` goals defined in each Makefile found in the directories in the list `$(SUBDIRS)`. By default, the output to the console is the combination of all outputs from the subtasks. Is there a way to simply output, e.g. `$* SUCCESS` or `$* FAILED` depending on the exit code?

I have tried using `@make...`, but this doesn't mask the output of the commands run from the other Makefiles.

Ideally, I would like to keep the sub-Makefiles unchanges, as I still occasionally want to use them directly and get the full output.

Comment: Why not redirect stdout & stderr? As in `make -C $* subtask 2>&1  > subtask/make.log` in your subtask command?

Comment: @TimothyBrown Thanks for pointing out that simple solution. If you write it as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be to get each subtask make write it's output to it's own log file. As in:

```
subtask_%:
        make -C $* subtask 2>&1 > subtask/make.log
```